# Bayesian Network Inference with Java Objects (Banjo Troubleshooting)

Tags: java, bioinformatics, bayesian-networks

Hopefully this is relevant. I am currently using Banjo to produce a network but I keep on getting this programming error: (Post-processing) Postprocessing cannot proceed because we can't process the high score network(s).

Could anyone perhaps shed some light on this? Dataset is relatively small (30 variables and 9 observations) and discretized. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is probably another message earlier in the log that tells you more information about your problem.
I just ran into the same error myself, it turn out that one of my input files the "mustBePresentEdgesFile" was not in the input directory. The error was shown in the log file embedded in the middle of some java traceback log. I have to admit the most prominent error message.

> (Post-processing) Postprocessing cannot proceed because we can't
>   process the high score network(s).

was not too helpful